# How to find VARIABLES with nothing but missing value?

Tags: syntax, spss

I know it is possible to find CASES with nothing but only missing values with help of
"select if nmss(V)=X"

but what should I do if I want to find VARIBALES with only missing values?

Say I have a dataset from someone else with over hundert variables, some variables are complete missing values (in my case, the questions/varibales  were not asked durning the interview), how can I find thoses varibales in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Data Preparation option, you can use Data > Validation > Validate Data to screen the variables.  If not, there is a function in the spssaux2.py module (available from the SPSS Community website - www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) called FindEmptyVariables that will do this.  It requires the Python Essentials.

Here is how to use it.
begin program.
import spssaux2
print spssaux2.FindEmptyVars()
end program.